# I want to locate the rows in the data frame where these particular values are present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

```
 companies = set(salarydf['company'])
 companies = str(companies)
 print(companies)
 import re
 re.findall("Tata Consultancy Services|TCS|Wipro|Infosys",companies)
 


 salarydf.loc[df['company'].str.contains('Tata Consultancy Services|TCS|Wipro|Infosys')]
```

[image: Code error image]

In the last line, I'm getting a "ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values".

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the column `company` contains `nan`.

You could use `fillna()` prior to `str` to ensure that all data are non null as follows:

```
 salarydf.loc[df['company'].fillna('').str.contains('Tata Consultancy Services|TCS|Wipro|Infosys')]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use pandas isin() function. Make a list of values you want to look for.

```
df[df.company.isin(your_list)]
```

By doing this, you will get all the rows in dataframe where your_list values are present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.findna()` to check NaN in your dataset and `.dropna()` to drop all NaN (Not a Number) values.

```py
salarydf.findna()
salarydf.dropna()
 
salarydf.loc[df['company'].str.contains('Tata Consultancy Services|TCS|Wipro|Infosys')]
```